# How do I use qUnit to test a javascript print method?

Tags: jquery, qunit

**How do I use qUnit to test a javascript *print* method?**

I have a file called *core.js* built on jQuery -

```
// API
var Screen = (function () { // private methods

    function print(text) {
        document.write(text);
    }

    return { // public methods
        print: function (text) {
            print(text);
        }
    };

}());

// MAIN
$(function () { // document ready

    Screen.print("Hello World.");

});
```

I also setup the qunit.js (and .css) files in an HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href='qunit.css' rel='stylesheet' />
</head>
<body>
    <div id='qunit'></div>
    <script src='qunit.js'></script>
    <script src='core.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm thinking that I have to add a script tag to the HTML document that imports core-test.js, which contains my unit tests. This is where I get confused...

core-test.js:

```
$(function () {
    test("print", function () {
        ok(Screen.print(text), "String is NOT null or undefined");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually that is almost correct.

**core-test.js** should have some type of assertion:

```
test("print", function () {
  ok(Screen.print("") !== null, "String is not null");
  ok(Screen.print("") !== undefined, "String is defined");
});
```

And the HTML document should import jQuery so that the $ identifier is recognized.

```
<body>
    <div id='qunit'></div>
    <script src='jquery-version.js'></script>
    <script src='qunit.js'></script>
    <script src='core.js'></script>
    <script src='core-test.js'></script>
</body>
```